# Dynamic One Page site that hides all sections except first child of each parent

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, show-hide

So I have a one page site that when a user clicks the navigation it shows that div associated with the ID in the anchor and hides all the other divs. Got that working ok.

However, I have sub sections within those divs.They are working ok except the first sub section child is not showing up for each page(parent div).

For example if I'm on the 'Resume' and click 'Work timeline', and then hit 'Projects' it hides the sub section of the 'Project' page due to it being clicked on the 'Resume'.

Is there something I can do to override when the users go to another page(div) it overrides what happen on the other page(div)

Any help would be really appreciated. 
DEMO:https://www.kevinhenriquez.com/projects/full/

HTML Code:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#cover" data-action="nav">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" data-action="nav">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume" data-action="nav">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-action="nav">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" data-action="nav">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<section id="cover" class="page-section">
........
</section>

<section id="projects" class="page-section">

      <section id="portfolio-sites" class="sub-section">
         ..................
      </section>
      <section id="client-sites" class="sub-section">
         ................................
      </section>

      <div class="page-section-nav">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#portfolio-sites" data-action="sub">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#client-sites" data-action="sub">Client</a></li>
           <li><a href="#school-sites" data-action="sub">School</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

</section>

<section id="resume" class="page-section">

      <section id="work-timeline" class="sub-section">
         ..................
      </section>
      <section id="technologies" class="sub-section">
         ................................
      </section>

      <div class="page-section-nav">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#work-timeline" data-action="sub">Timeline</a></li>
           <li><a href="#technologies" data-action="sub">Technologies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

</section>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    var pageSection = $('.page-section');
    var subSection = $('.sub-section');

    var navLink = $('nav ul li a');
    var subLink = $('.page-section-nav li a');

    var sectionToggle = {
      nav:   
        function (event) { 
            pageSection.hide();
            $(this.getAttribute('href')).show();

            navLink.removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
            $('#nav-trigger').prop( "checked", false);
        },

      sub: 
        function (event) {
            subSection.hide();
            $(this.getAttribute('href')).show();

            subLink.removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).addClass('highlight'); 

        }
    };


    pageSection.not(":first").hide();
    subSection.not(":first").hide();

    $("a[data-action]").on("click", function (event) {
      var link = $(this),
          action = link.data("action");

      event.preventDefault();

      if( typeof sectionToggle[action] === "function" ) {
        sectionToggle[action].call(this, event);
      } 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could look like this:

```
function hideNotFirstChild(ancestor){
    let allchilds=ancestor.children;
    for each(allchilds as child ){
        if(child!=ancestor.firstchild){
            child.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Applied function to all the nodes of the pages because you've to know ancestor in order to know who's the first child.

I barely use jQuery here (only the .hide() method) because it won't change much.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by adding on the nav toggle function :

$('.sub-section:first-child).show();

and removing:

subSection.not("first").hide();

Thanks for the help. This is what I did:

```
var sectionToggle = {
              nav:   
                function (event) { 
                    pageSection.hide();
                    $(this.getAttribute('href')).show();
                    $('.sub-section:first-child').show();

                    navLink.removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).addClass('highlight');
                    $('#nav-trigger').prop( "checked", false);
                },

              sub: 
                function (event) {
                    subSection.hide();
                    $(this.getAttribute('href')).show();

                    subLink.removeClass('highlight');
                    $(this).addClass('highlight'); 

                }
            };
```